# How to reveal hidden text by sliding UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, animation

I'm trying to place a date field to the left of a cell in `UITableView` that is revealed when the user slides the cell from left to right.  When released, the cell should spring back into place, hiding the date field.  Does anyone know how to do this?  Is it handled in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
```

or defined somehow within a custom cell?

Comment: Are you looking for something similar to iMessage app where the dates are displayed right next to the chat bubble on swipe ?

Comment: That's basically the same idea

Comment: That probably works with a pan, but that UI might be completely different as the chat bubbles are on opposite sides and you have enough space to show dates on the right side without having to reload top chat bubbles.

Comment: I've got that covered if just work with individual cells for each chat line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldnt use the editing delegate as you posted.

Put the cells content in a `UIView`, in a `UIScrollView`, then setup the information behind the `UIScrollView` you wish to reveal.

Then on the scroll `delegate`, `scrollViewDidEndDragging`, set the contentOffset back to 0 animated.

EDIT: Pan gesture example

If you wish for the simplest route, setup your cell with a customContentView that is the size of your cell, add the pan gesture to this, then setup and buttons you want, in my example below I had a button each side.

Note: This is swift 2, but should be easily translatable, I made this a longgg time ago when swift 2 was released, it could do with refactoring

```
var savedX = 0 as CGFloat
var buttonWidth = 60 as CGFloat
var open = false

func panGestureHandler(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if gesture.state == .Changed {
        let translation = gesture.translationInView(tagView)

        let difference = -translation.x

        if difference > 0 && !allowScrollRight {
            return
        }

        let newConstant = savedX + difference

        tagViewCenterXConstraint.constant = newConstant

        let alpha = abs(tagViewCenterXConstraint.constant) / buttonWidth

        deleteButton.alpha = min(alpha, 1)
        followButton.alpha = min(alpha, 1)

        if let action = swipe {
            action(self)
        }
    }

    if gesture.state == .Ended {
        let translation = gesture.translationInView(self)

        let trans = fabs(translation.x)

        open = !open && trans > buttonWidth

        if open {
            if(translation.x > 0){
                resetRight(true)
            } else {
                if allowScrollRight {
                    resetLeft(true)
                }
            }
        } else {
            resetView(true){

            }
        }
    }
}

 func resetLeft (animated : Bool) {
        tagViewCenterXConstraint.constant = self.buttonWidth
        savedX = self.buttonWidth


    if animated {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState], animations: { () -> Void in
            self.tagView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.leftView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.rightView.layoutIfNeeded()

            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
        })
    }
}

func resetRight (animated : Bool) {
    tagViewCenterXConstraint.constant = -self.buttonWidth
    savedX = -self.buttonWidth

    if animated {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState], animations: { () -> Void in
            self.tagView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.leftView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.rightView.layoutIfNeeded()

            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
        })
    }
}

func resetView (animated : Bool, completion: () -> Void ) {
    tagViewCenterXConstraint.constant = 0
    savedX = 0
    open = false

    if animated {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState], animations: { () -> Void in
            self.tagView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.leftView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.rightView.layoutIfNeeded()

            }, completion: { (finished) -> Void in
                completion()
        })
    } else {
        completion()
    }
}
```

Comment: My goal is to also keep the editActionsForRowAt to reveal some buttons on the right side, but to reveal the date text on the left side using a pan motion.  If I use the scrollView, I'll loose that capability.  I've been looking meanwhile at this tutorial, from Ray Wenderlich, https://www.raywenderlich.com/77974/making-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-like-clear-in-swift-part-1 which  suggests using a pan gesture recogniser.  I wondered if that would work in combination with the edit delegate.

Comment: In this case I would use the scrollview for both sides, making your own buttons, that way you can do a simple check to see which way it has been moved to check if to revert it back to its original position

Comment: Does this bring in memory management problems?  Most of what I've read points to tableviews being better for large arrays of data

Comment: You still use a tableview, but inside the cell, you use a scrollview, putting the cells movable content inside the scrollview and the buttons / date label behind the scrollview

Comment: you can actually do it without a scrollview and just add a pan gesture to the contentview of the cell

Comment: that's what I was thinking.  I haven't tried that in a cell before but it looks the most promising approach

Comment: I will add some exmaple code of a pan gesture inside a cell